# Is this the correct way to pass a struct by value in ctypes?

Tags: python, ctypes

I'm having difficulty using Python's ctypes to call into native code that passes a struct by value when that struct contains only an array. Am I doing something wrong here? The following code works for some types and array sizes, but dies with the message "`Aborted (core dumped)`" for others. It seems to fail when the size of the struct is 16 bytes.

Here's roughly what I'm doing (see further down for the complete runnable version):

```
libsum = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary('./libsum.so')

class MyStruct(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [("data", ctypes.c_uint32 * 4)]

m = MyStruct()

# ... initialize value of m ...

result = libsum.sum(m))
```

In order to call a function declared like this:

```
struct ArrayStruct {
    std::uint32_t data[4];
};

extern "C" int64_t sum(struct ArrayStruct array);
```

I'm running this on 64-bit Ubuntu and trying both Python 3.4 and Python 2.7. I get the same results in both cases - whenever the size of the array is between 9 and 16 bytes the program aborts.

It seems like I must be doing something stupid, but I can't figure out what.

### sum.cpp

```cpp
#include <cstdint>

using std::size_t;

struct ArrayStruct {
    // We'll define ARRAY_TYPE and ARRAY_SIZE on the
    // command-line when we compile.
    std::ARRAY_TYPE data[ARRAY_SIZE];
};

extern "C" int64_t sum(struct ArrayStruct array)
{
    int64_t acc=0;
    for (size_t i=0; i!=ARRAY_SIZE; ++i)
    {
        acc+=array.data[i];
    }
    return acc;
}
```

### sum.py

```
import ctypes
import sys

def main():
    array_size = int(sys.argv[1])
    array_type = sys.argv[2]

    libsum = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary('./libsum.so')

    ArrType = getattr(ctypes, 'c_' + array_type) * array_size

    class MyStruct(ctypes.Structure):
        _fields_ = [("data", ArrType)]

    m=MyStruct()
    for i in range(array_size):
        m.data[i]=i

    print(libsum.sum(m))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

### Build/run

```
$ g++ -g -shared -Wall -fPIC sum.cpp -o libsum.so -std=c++11 -D ARRAY_SIZE=16 -D ARRAY_TYPE=uint8_t && python sum.py 16 uint8
Aborted (core dumped)
```

### Results:

```
                           ARRAY_SIZE
ARRAY_TYPE      1     2     4     8    16    32    64

     uint8      0     1     6    28 crash   496  2016
    uint16      0     1     6 crash   120   496  2016
    uint32      0     1 crash    28   120   496  2016
    uint64      0 crash     6    28   120   496  2016

      int8      0     1     6    28 crash   496  2016
     int16      0     1     6 crash   120   496  2016
     int32      0     1 crash    28   120   496  2016
     int64      0 crash     6    28   120   496  2016
```

---

As I suspect this may be a bug, I've reported it here: http://bugs.python.org/issue22273

Comment: Passing by value is deliberate, yes. I'm actually trying to debug a call to SDL_JoystickGetGUIDString in SDL2: http://hg.libsdl.org/SDL/file/92ca74200ea5/include/SDL_joystick.h so the choice of a struct passed by value is not mine to make. (I do have a workaround for this case, but I want to figure out why it won't work, and possibly figure out where to report a bug.)

Comment: Hi, thanks for posting this.  I've run into an issue passing a struct by value with Ctypes as well.  My example is a little different in that the struct lives on a C layer and this is cast to a C++ class object which is responsible for holding the data.  Let me know if you or anyone else would find my example useful in the debugging process

Comment: That bug was finally addressed by https://github.com/python/cpython/pull/15839